# Unique constraint on inserting new row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a SQL statement within PostgreSQL 12 and I first created an unique constraint like:

```
CONSTRAINT post_comment_response_approval__tm_response__uidx UNIQUE (post_comment_response_id, team_member_id)
```

On a SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO post_comment_response_approval (post_comment_response_id, team_member_id, approved, note)
        VALUES (:postCommentResponseId, :workspaceMemberId, :approved, :note)
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT post_comment_response_approval__tm_response__uidx DO
        UPDATE SET approved = :approved, note = :note
```

Fist, I wanted to use it for the same row whenever ever some action is made, but now I just want to make sure the API shows them if multiple actions have been submitted by the same member.

An example is that someone might suggest a change, then that change is made, then that person who suggested it later approves it. That would generate multiple `post_comment_response_approval` rows for that approver.

Is there a way to make it happen without removing unique constraint or maybe it should be deleted? I am new with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question in detail. But I think I understood what you need. You can use PostgreSQL partial indexing.
Examples for you:

```
CREATE TABLE table6 (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    id2 int4 NOT null, 
    approve bool NULL   
);

-- creating partial indexing 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table6_id_idx ON table6 (id,id2) where approve is true; 


insert into table6 (id, id2, approve) values (1, 1, false);
-- success insert 

insert into table6 (id, id2, approve) values (1, 1, false);
-- success insert 

insert into table6 (id, id2, approve) values (1, 1, false);
-- success insert 

insert into table6 (id, id2, approve) values (1, 1, true);
-- success insert 

insert into table6 (id, id2, approve) values (1, 1, true);
-- error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table6_id_idx"
```

So, you get unique fields by condition.